# How to assign Model Id to HTML element Created by JQuery?

Tags: html, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to create a button that when clicked creates a list item and adds it to an existing list. I'm trying to achieve this by using JQuery. I'd very much like to use bootstrap on the list item and append a `<span>` tag to each list item also with a bootstrap class. I'm having trouble with appending the `span` tag and with assigning an id to each list item for later use.

this is what I got so far:

Button:

```
<button onclick="AddItem('@Dish.DishName','@Dish.Price',@Dish.DishId)">@Dish.DishName</button>
```

JQuery function:

```
function AddItem(Name, Price, ID) {
            $(".order").append(
                $('<li/>').attr("id", ID).addClass("list-group-item").text(Name/* + "          " + Price*/));
            $(ID).append(
                $('<span/>').addClass("badge").text(Price)

            );
        }
```

Would appreciate any help or advice

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In regard to appending the span, an ID must must be selected with a "#", but it looks like it is never modified after being passed into the function. Try rewriting the selector as a template literal:

```
$(`#${ID}`).append
```

or string concatenation:

```
$("#" + ID).append
```

Comment: Thanx Pavlos, should i have modified it and if so then how? also if i wanted later on to use queryselectorAll on a couple of list itemes with the same id how would i go about doing that?

Comment: As shown in my above answer, adding the "#" via a template literal or string concatenation.

If querySelectorAll is called within the function, you would again add the "#" via the above methods (though elements technically shouldn't share IDs, only classes). 

Since querySelectorAll creates an array, you could then iterate it through a for loop to append something to each element:

`const arr = document.querySelectorAll("#" + ID);

for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  $( arr[i]).append(//what you want to append)
}`

Comment: I created a code pen to demonstrate querySelectorAll:

https://codepen.io/PavlosKaralis/pen/dyGROZG